# Why does this LDAP query return an array with just a 0

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap, openldap

I'm new to LDAP and Active Directory. I'm trying to fetch the Email-ID of an authenticated user using the following code. However when I run it, all I get is an array with a 0 in it.

Here's the code

```
$server ='ldaps://DOMAIN'; 
$username = 'DOMAIN\UID'; 
$password = 'PASSWORD';

$base_dn = 'dc=DOMAIN';
$search_filter = 'dn=UID'; 
$attributes = ['mail']; 

$ldap = ldap_connect($server);
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_bind($ldap, $username, $password); 
$search = ldap_search($ldap, $base_dn, $search_filter, $attributes);
$data = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $search);

foreach($data as $dataPoint)
    {
        echo $dataPoint;
        echo "<hr>";
    }
```

This outputs just a 0 with a horizontal line below it.

The most challenging thing here is that there is no error message whatsoever and I'm not very familiar with LDAP nor with Active Directory.

Any idea as to why this could be happening.

Comment: Searching LDAP can be a pain - especially if you are not familiar with the structure that is set up. I found that downloading the MS AD browser (small app that lets you view the structure in a tree like manner) makes it much much easier to ensure that the searches you run are performing the right search. Once you are, the data actually comes back in an array with MANY fields - so try using print_r to view each bit brought back to find the right elements that contain the email ID.

Comment: Thanks a ton!! this helped me more than anything. Issue was with my base domain, was able to identify the right one only cause of AD browser

Comment: No problems, I remember when I first started doing LDAP searches, it was hell as well until a friend suggested I browse the tree to make sure I was using the correct searches :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see several things that could potentially be causing problems from the code above:

- Do you really mean to use `ldaps://`? Usually that is not what you want to do. If you want to use an encrypted connection you should use [ldap_start_tls](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-start-tls.php%20ldap_start_tls) and the call should be made after `ldap_connect`. For the purpose of testing I would just change it to `ldap://`.
- Your `$base_dn` variable seems to be missing part of the domain. That should not be the NETBIOS name of your domain, but rather the fully qualified domain name. So if your domain was `domain.com` then the base dn would be `dc=domain,dc=com`.
- Your search filter (`$search_filter`) is not properly formed. If you are trying to retrieve a user object from LDAP given an account name, you could use a search filter like: `(sAMAccountName=UID)`

To get a better idea of what may be going wrong you can use [ldap_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-error.php%20ldap_error) and call it after you connect: `echo "Error: ".ldap_error($ldap);`. You can do this after any LDAP related call to get more information on what may have gone wrong.

Comment: yes the issue was with the base domain thanks to you and $fluffeh was able to identify the right format and rectify accordingly